# How to update a ReactJS component after fetch request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Hi I am attempting to update a react component, which is not working.  When a user clicks a button on a sibling component, a post request is made to my api.  The purpose of this component is to create a list of those events by:

1. First querying my api for those posted event ids
2. Then loop thru the event ids, and for each make a fetch request to an external api where the info on the events are always updated.
3. As each event is queried from the external api, the results are pushed to an empty array
4. and finally the state is set when a new event is pushed into the array.

This is working, but when a new event is saved to my api this component will not re-render.  Here is my code, which is not updating:

```
class EventList extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        userEvents: []
    }
}

//Create a function to load active user's saved events in api
loadEvents = () => {
    const ActiveUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ActiveUser"))

    //Get active user's events from vetharbor.json
    fetch(`http://localhost:8088/events?userId=${ActiveUser.id}`)

    //convert get to json data
    .then(r => r.json())

    .then(allEvents => {
        let events = []
        //for each event tied to active user's id, loop thru and ...
        allEvents.forEach(event => {

            //make a fetch request to eventbrite with the event's id
            fetch(`https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/${event.id}/?token=MY_API_Token`)

            //convert response to json
            .then(r => r.json())

            //return the data???
            .then(ue => {
               events.push(ue)
               // this.userEvents = events
                this.setState({
                    userEvents: events
                })
            })
        }) 
    })
}

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if(this.state.userEvents !== nextState.userEvents){
        return true
    }

}

componentDidUpdate(){
    this.loadEvents()
}

//run the function in a component did mount
componentDidMount(){
    console.log("component did mount")
    this.loadEvents()
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="event-list">
        <h3>These are events</h3>
        {this.state.userEvents.map(ues => {
           return <h1 key={ues.id}>{ues.name.text}</h1>
        })}

        </div>
        );

    }
}

export default EventList
```

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        if(this.state.userEvents === nextState.userEvents){
            return true
        }
    }
```

In your case shouldComponentUpdate does not return true because the old userEvents and new userEvents are different and logic is incorrect. 
Try changing it to :

```
if(!(this.state.userEvents).equals(nextState.userEvents)){
                return true
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realize my mistake with the logic, so I changed the logic to read:  if(this.state.userEvents !== nextState.userEvents){  return true  } , but this now causes an infinite loop.  I've been told it's from the setState in my loadEvents, but I'm not sure how to fix.

Comment: Comparing arrays with !== Will not always work. You can use `.equals()` instead.

Comment: Yes, I tried the way you suggested and I received the error:  "TypeError: this.state.userEvents.equals is not a function"

Comment: `!((this.state.userEvents).equals(nextState.userEvents))`

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that there was an error in my logic, as a result I modified my code above to the following, which now updates my code (with an infinite loop, but it does update)

from:

> shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
>       if(this.state.userEvents === nextState.userEvents){
>           return true
>       }

to:

> shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
>        if(this.state.userEvents !== nextState.userEvents){
>            return true
>        }

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is caused by componentDidUpdate fetching the data again, setState causes componentDidUpdate to be called again which loads data which again calls setState.
Removing componentDidUpdate or adding conditional logic if you really need it (you almost never do) should fix it.